# How to return object from map of some other type?

Tags: rx-java2

I am trying to write bulk save or update kind of functionality. Where in records are read from the CSV file and converted to the appropriate class and then save or update is performed for that record.

Below are the steps for save or update

1. Get from DB by emailId.(Maybe is returned)
2. If the user exists call save else to update.
3. In case of successful DB operation, return Single of type Report.
   Here Report is a user-defined class.

```
 Flowable.fromPublisher(userRepository.findByEmail(user.emailId)).firstElement()
```

This code returns MayBe, on this, I want to call Save/Update, which returns Single or error. In any case, I want to Return Single of type Report

Below is code example I have tried in blocking the way, but I want to do it in non-blocking way

```
   @Override
    Single<BulkUploadReport> processData(String nextLine) {
        List<Object> errors = new ArrayList<>()

        Single.create({ emitter ->

            def parsedString = parseCsv(nextLine, readFirstLine: true, columnNames: columnNames)
            for (record in parsedString) {


                try {
                    User user = parseRecord(record)
                    List<String> roles = parseRoles(record[14])


                   User dbUser =  Flowable.fromPublisher(userRepository.findByEmail(user.emailId)).firstElement().blockingGet()

                    if(dbUser == null){
                         userService.save(user, user.emailId, roles, saveUserkey).blockingGet()

                    }else{
                        user.userkey = dbUser.userkey
                         Single.fromPublisher(userRepository.updateUser(saveUserkey, user)).blockingGet()

                    }
                    emitter.onSuccess(new BulkUploadReport(record[0] as int, true, null))
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("Error in bulk update.Handled grac8efully:  ${e.getMessage()}")
                    ArrayList<String> err = e.getMessage().tokenize(",") as ArrayList<String>
                    errors.addAll(err)
                    emitter.onSuccess(new BulkUploadReport(record[0] as int, false,errors))
                }

            }

        }) as Single<BulkUploadReport>
    }
```

**UserRepository:**

```
 Publisher<User> updateUser(String saveUserKey, User user)
 Publisher<User> findByEmail(String emailId)
 Publisher<Success> insertUser(User user)
```

I am new to RxJava and I don't understand how to chain these events.

Comment: Can you post signatures of `userRepositiry` functions, used in that snippet? By the way, when you use `Single` type from `Reactive Streams`, you should respect it's contact - `onSuccess` should be called only once or never. But you call it inside for-loop. In that case, it'll be better to use `Observable`.

Comment: @ConstOrVar updated the question

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should avoid all the `blockingGet()` calls (which is not really the philosophy of Rx) and tries to chain process with Rx methods calls.
In your code snippet, it's unclear if you are trying to process a list of user or a single user from a CSV. May be if you could give the signature of `parseCsv()`, it would be clearer.
It's also not clear which method can throw an Exception.

If ever a single user is extracted from a CSV, here is a pseudo-code answer that may do the trick:

```java
public Single<BulkUploadReport> processData(String line) {
    final Record record = parseCsv(line, true, columNames);
    final User user = parseRecord(record);
    final List<String> roles = parseRoles(record);

    return Flowable.fromPublisher(userRepository.findByEmail(user.emailId))
                   .firstElement()
                   .switchIfEmpty(Maybe.just(userService.save(user, user.emailId, roles, saveUserkey)))
                   .map(aUser -> new BulkUploadReport(record, false))
                   .toSingle();
}
```

Hope this helps.